# Graph in popup and separate Div in Leaflet

Tags: highcharts, leaflet

I wonder if anyone can tell me what is wrong in my code please? I want to be able to select a polygon and show a graph in a popup using leaflet and highchart. I have managed to create the graph in the popup, but the line is missing on it, and I also get a separate div showing the same chart (and the line) at the bottom of my web page which I don't want. Can anyone tell me how to get the line to show on the chart in the popup and to remove the separate chart? Here is my code.enter code here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Quick Start - Leaflet</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!--include leaflet CSS file-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/leaflet.css" />
    <link rel="markers" type="images/marker-icon" href="images/marker-icon.png" />

<!--include Leaflet Javascript file-->
<!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->

    <script src="js/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src='http://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.js'></script>
    <script src="js/esri-leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body>

 <!--Put a div element with a certain id where you want your map to be:  -->

   <div id="map" style="width: 1000px; height: 800px;"></div>
   <div id="chartcontainer" class="highchart" style="width: 500px; height: 200px;"></div>

  <!-- First we’ll initialize the map and set its view to our chosen geographical coordinates and a zoom level:-->
  <script>

    var mymap = L.map('map', {
            zoomControl:true, maxZoom:28, minZoom:1
        }).fitBounds([[51.0269253989,-1.34762355597],[51.1990603009,-0.951310026203]]);

    L.esri.basemapLayer('Imagery').addTo(mymap);        

//loads geoserver layer as WMS
 var field_boundaries = L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:1997/geoserver/RSAC/wms", {
    layers: 'RSAC:results_clipped_with_growth_small_new',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    version: '1.1.0',
    attribution: "myattribution"
    });


//loads the geojson layer
    var owsrootUrl = 'http://localhost:1997/geoserver/RSAC/wms';
    var defaultParameters = {
        service : 'WFS',
        version : '2.0',
        request : 'GetFeature',
        typeName : 'RSAC:results_clipped_with_growth_small_new',
        outputFormat : 'json',
        format_options : 'callback:getJson',
        SrsName : 'EPSG:4326'
    };
var parameters = L.Util.extend(defaultParameters);
var URL = owsrootUrl + L.Util.getParamString(parameters);
var ajax = $.ajax({
    url : URL,
    dataType : 'json',
    jsonpCallback : 'getJson',
    success : function (response) {
    L.geoJson(response, {
        onEachFeature: function (feature, url) {
        url.on('click', function(e){

                    var chartplotoptions ={
                        chart: {
                            type: 'line'
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'Growth'
                        },

                        xAxis: {
                            allowDecimals: true,
                            categories: ['20151114', '20151126', '20151208', '20151220', '20160113', '20160125', '20160206', '20160218', '20160301', '20160313', '20160325', '20160406', '20160418', '20160430', '20160512', '20160524', '20160605', '20160629', '20160723', '20160804', '20160816'],
                            labels: {
                                formatter: function () {
                                    return this.value; 
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                                startOnTick: false,
                                minPadding: 0.05,
                            title: {
                                text: 'Crop Growth',

                            },
                            labels: {
                                formatter: function () {
                                    return this.value;
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        tooltip: {
                            pointFormat: '{series.name}{point.y}'
                        },
                        plotOptions: {

                                area: {
                                pointStart: -20,
                                threshold: 10,
                                marker: {
                                    enabled: false,
                                    symbol: 'circle',
                                    radius: 2,
                                    states: {
                                        hover: {
                                            enabled: false
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        series: [{
                            name: 'Growth',
                            data: [parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20151114),parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20151126),parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20151208), parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20151220), parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20160113), parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20150125), parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20160206), parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20160218), parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20160301), parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20160313), parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20160325), parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20160406), parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20160418), parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20160430), parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20160512), parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20160524), parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20160605), parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20160629), parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20160723), parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20160804), parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20160816)]
                        }, 

                        ]
                    };


                    $('#chartcontainer').highcharts(chartplotoptions);
                    url.bindPopup($('#chartcontainer').html());
                    url.openPopup();  
                    });
                }

             }).addTo(mymap);
         }
     });     

  </script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Next time please make sure you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the div element in your HTML markup. You can create one on the fly in your `onEachFeature` function and add it to the popup. Also, you need to initialize your highchart after the popup has opened, not before. In code with comments:

```js
new L.GeoJSON(feature, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {

        // Create div with class name highchart
        var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'highchart');

        // Bind popup to layer with div as content
        layer.bindPopup(div);

        // Handle event when popup opens
        layer.on('popupopen', function (e) {

            console.log(e.target);  // layer object
            console.log(e.target.feature); // layer's feature object
            console.log(e.popup); // popup object
            console.log(e.popup.getContent()); // the div

            // Now do the highcharts stuff
            Highcharts.chart(e.popup.getContent(), { /**/ });
        });
    }
});
```

And don't forget to set the div's dimensions with CSS:

```css
.highchart {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
}
```