# Missing line on chart in popup

Tags: highcharts, popup, leaflet

I wonder if anyone can see where I am going wrong. I am trying to get my line to appear on my chart in a popup. It works OK if I have the chart in a separate div but not in a popup. I am pulling data from Geoserver and I can see all the data fine. I am using leaflet and Highcharts.

Here is the relevant code.

```
    var field_boundaries = L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:1997/geoserver/RSAC/wms", {
        layers: 'RSAC:results_clipped_with_growth_small_new',
        format: 'image/png',
        transparent: true,
        version: '1.1.0',
        attribution: "myattribution"
        });


//loads the geojson layer
    var owsrootUrl = 'http://localhost:1997/geoserver/RSAC/wms';
    var defaultParameters = {
        service : 'WFS',
        version : '1.1.0',
        request : 'GetFeature',
        typeName : 'RSAC:results_clipped_with_growth_small_new',
        outputFormat : 'json',
        format_options : 'callback:getJson',
        SrsName : 'EPSG:4326'
    };
var parameters = L.Util.extend(defaultParameters);
var URL = owsrootUrl + L.Util.getParamString(parameters);
var ajax = $.ajax({
    url : URL,
    dataType : 'json',
    jsonpCallback : 'getJson',
    success : function (response) {
    new L.geoJson(response, {
        onEachFeature: function (feature, url) {

        // Create div with class name highchart
        var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'highchart');

        // Bind popup to layer with div as content
        url.bindPopup(div);

        // Handle event when popup opens
        url.on('popupopen', function (e) {

            console.log(e.target);  // layer object
            console.log(e.target.feature); // layer's feature object
            console.log(e.popup); // popup object
            console.log(e.popup.getContent()); // the div


        $(".highchart").on('click', function onPopUpOpen(e){

                    $(".highchart")(e.popup.getContent(),{
                        chart: {
                            type: 'line',
                            renderTo: 'bindPopup'
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'Growth'
                        },
                        series: {
                            lineWidth:1,
                            colour: '#FF0000'
                            },

                        xAxis: {
                            allowDecimals: true,
                            categories: ['20151114', '20151126', '20151208', '20151220', '20160113', '20160125', '20160206', '20160218', '20160301', '20160313', '20160325', '20160406', '20160418', '20160430', '20160512', '20160524', '20160605', '20160629', '20160723', '20160804', '20160816'],
                            labels: {
                                formatter: function () {
                                    return this.value; 
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                                startOnTick: false,
                                minPadding: 0.05,
                            title: {
                                text: 'Crop Growth',

                            },
                            labels: {
                                formatter: function () {
                                    return this.value;
                                }
                            }
                        },

                       tooltip: {
                            pointFormat: '{series.name}{point.y}'
                        },
                        plotOptions: {
                                line: {
                                    dataLabels: {
                                        enabled: false
                                    },
                                    enableMouseTracking: true
                                    }
                                },

                        series: [{
                            cursor: 'pointer',
                            color: '#4D4D4D',
                            lineWidth: 3,
                            name: 'Growth',
                            data: [parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20151114),parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20151126),parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20151208), parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20151220), parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20160113), parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20160125), parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20160206), parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20160218), parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20160301), parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20160313), parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20160325), parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20160406), parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20160418), parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20160430), parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20160512), parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20160524), parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20160605), parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20160629), parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20160723), parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20160804), parseFloat(feature.properties.Date_20160816)]
                        }, 
                        ]

                        });
                        // Create the chart
                        //var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

                });

             }).addTo(mymap);
         }
       });
      }
    });
```

Comment: I already gave you a working answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45349034/graph-in-popup-and-separate-div-in-leaflet You must wait for the popup to open, using the popupopen event, then in your handler function initialize the chart.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have incorporated your comments but I am now getting error messages which relate to the console.log lines do these need to be edited in any way? I'm getting an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContent' of undefined where I have added line 'Highcharts.chart(e.popup.getContent(),{'

Comment: I forgot to mention that my popup is now blank.

Comment: Please, provide us with a working JSFiddle demo where this occurs.

Comment: I think it is going to be a little hard for me to set up a working example in fiddle as I don't have that much experience and I am pulling the data from my local Geoserver. I think the problem is related to this part of the code: url.bindPopup(div);
  url.on('click', function(e){
  
   $(".highchart")(e.popup.getContent()),{

                        chart: {                                                                              
 as the error is related to this 'getContent'. Can you see any problems with this?

Comment: I have updated my code to show the changes which iH8 has suggested